# How do I remove the delay the countdown timer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-hooks

I have made a countdown timer but every time the site is loaded, the timer takes 1.5s to load in from the default 0 values. Is there any way to preload it or make it appear instantly?

```
function Timer() {
  const [days, setDays] = useState(0);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  const deadline = "February, 17, 2023";

  const getTime = () => {
    const time = Date.parse(deadline) - Date.now();

    setDays(Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    setHours(Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));
    setMinutes(Math.floor((time / 1000 / 60) % 60));
    setSeconds(Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => getTime(deadline), 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Comment: BTW, `"February, 17, 2023"` is not a standard date/time format and I'm doubtful it will be consistently parsed by all JS platforms - you should use the unambiguous ISO 8601 format instead: `2023-02-17` and use the UTC members of `Date` instead of the local (i.e. non-UTC) members as those will have your local computer timezone offset applied (so if you're in the US then the date would be reported as `2023-02-16`).

Comment: Please create a working example to check for us https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the first time you evaluate the timer is after the initial 1s delay. The easiest fix would be to call `getTime` before creating the interval:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // This will run after the component mounts
  getTime();

  // This will then run every second afterwards
  const interval = setInterval(() => getTime(), 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```